# ¿Qué significa "Me parto y me mondo"?

Tags: expresiones, significado, españa

Yo estaba mirando un video de internet gracioso y, en la mayoría de los chistes, cuando termina de contarlos dice la siguiente frase:

> Me parto y me mondo.

¿Qué significa?

Comment: Le puse el tag España porque por Colombia (y pensaría que en el resto de latinoamérica es igual) no significa nada. Nunca la he oído.

Comment: @DGaleano Pensé que como tenía la palabra `y` debía tener la etiqueta `conjunción`... ok, entonces es de España solamente.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En la entrada del DRAE para *[risa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WVeu9LN)* verás que hay muchas locuciones verbales con dicha palabra: morirse de risa, desternillarse de risa, **partirse de risa**, mearse de risa, **mondarse de risa**, etc. Todas ellas significan reírse mucho y con ganas. Algunas se pueden simplificar:

> ¡Me meo!
>
> ¡Me parto!

Por tanto, dicha literalmente la expresión podría indicar que el hablante se ha reído enormemente tras oír alguna gracia. Sin embargo, ten cuidado porque (al menos que yo recuerde), creo que esa expresión se puso de moda precisamente a la inversa, dicha en tono completamente sarcástico (al menos aquí en España). A mí mismo me la han dicho más de una vez en tono serio tras soltar algún chiste malo, para hacerme ver que lo dicho no tenía ni pizca de gracia.

Comment: Añadiría que por separado sí que son reírse mucho, sin ningún otro tipo de sentido. Y por aquí (País Vasco, norte de España) muchas veces la he escuchado para hacer la gracia, porque suena bastante estúpida. Quiero decir, significando que te hace gracia, pero quieres ser gracioso a tu vez al expresarlo.

Comment: ¿Y por qué los españoles "_se parten_" y "_se mondan_"? Lo que me imagino es una risa tan grandiosa que su cuerpo se destruye en pedazos y, como si fueran una manzana, toman cada trozo de si mismos y se quitan la cáscara a cuchilladas. Acá en Chile somos mucho más simples, nos cagamos de la risa nomás.

Comment: @Rodrigo de todas las expresiones posibles, _mondarse de risa_ ha sido siempre la que me sonaba más raro, las otras son bastante más literales, como _mearse de risa_. La de _partirse de risa_ creo que se refiere a partirse el pecho de tanto reír. Podrías formular una pregunta acerca del sentido figurado de _mondarse_.

Answer (score 2):

Mondar significa pelar una fruta, por ejemplo, mondar una manzana significaría pelar o quitar la cáscara a una manzana. Por otro lado es común la frase "me mondo de risa" o "me parto de risa" que simplificadas son, "me parto" o "me mondo".

Puedes usar las dos a la vez, pero claro en el orden correcto, es decir, el orden en el que lo harías con una fruta. "Mondar" o pelar y luego "partir" o cortar, así que la frase para expresar de modo simplificado que "mueres de risa" es, "me mondo y me parto".

Hace algunos años hubo una serie llamada "Aida", donde uno de los personajes, Luisma, que era tonto y divertido, lo decía al revés "me parto y me mondo" cosa que si lo hicieras con una fruta seria absurdo, y así fue como se quedó como frase graciosa o de chiste para recordar.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, la verdad es que no significa nada: es una frase creada por el actor español Paco León, quien interpreta a Luisma: un ex drogadicto que quedó tonto después del abuso de las drogas. La serie se llama "Aída" y se la recomiendo, es muy buena.

Comment: Mondarse significa reírse mucho y con ganas, partirse de risa también es reise mucho y a veces se utiliza solamente partirse. No sé si antes del personaje de Luisma se usaban las dos a la vez como expresión pero por separado por supuesto que ya existían.